# Using HTMLAgilityPack to parse an HTML string not from a URL

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to take a string that I have marked up through vb.net code and cross-check it with the text file it came from originally. This is for proofreading the html output.

To do this, I need to parse an HTML snippet that does not come from a URL.

The examples of HTMLAgilityPack I have seen get their input from a URL. Is there a way to parse a string of marked-up text that does not include a header or similar parts of a well-formed webpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To parse a string containing an HTML snippet rather than a file or URL, you can use the HtmlDocument as @Oded suggested, but instead of using doc.Load(), use doc.LoadHtml().

```
String HtmlSnippet = "<p>Example <strong>Html</strong> snippet</p>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(HtmlSnippet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `WebDocument` use `HtmlDocument`:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
```

It is the first thing on the [HAP examples page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples).